# Hostsファイル内で1つのホスト名に対して異なるIPアドレスを同時に登録することは問題ないですか？

Tags: hosts

hostsファイルの使い方について質問です。

システム構成としては、WindowsのIISが起動しているWebサーバー(No1,No2)が2台あります。
クライアント側は基本的にNo1にアクセスしてWebアプリを使用します。
ここで要望としては、No1のWebサーバーが機能停止した場合、No2にアクセスするようにしたいです。

DNSサーバーやロードバランサーがない環境なのでクライアント側のPCのhostsに
192.168.0.1 myApp
192.168.0.2 myApp
と登録を考えています。

hostsファイルをこのように同じ名前×違うIPで登録することは問題ないでしょうか。もしくは別の良い方法があればご教授いただきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

質問の範囲がわからないのですが、

> hostsファイルをこのように同じ名前×違うIPで登録することは問題ないでしょうか。

もちろん問題ありません。ただし、アクセスする度に 192.168.0.1 / 192.168.0.2 どちらが選択されるか不明です。
Webサーバーとのことですので、最初のリクエストと次のリクエストが別のサーバーに送られる可能性が生じます。両サーバーでセッション情報等を共有してください。共有できていないとエラーになるはずです。
（セッション情報の共有ができているならDNSくらい用意されてそうにも思いますが…。）

Comment: sayuriさんもおっしゃっていますが、出来るととしても、その後の面倒というかリスクがあるので、通常、付加分散なりクラスタリングソフトによるフローティングipなどに任せたいものです。ARRによる振り分けなど検討されてはイかがでしょうかhttps://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ee886279.aspx

Comment: 質問の範囲がわかりづらかったですね…上記記載の通り「hostsファイルをこのように同じ名前×違うIPで登録することは問題ないでしょうか。」の部分が質問になります。セッションの問題について理解しました。 あとわいと様のコメントにあるARRについても調べて見ます。ありがとうございます。